# Ascending the div based on rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of divs with data. Each div contains a custom data. Each div have data like a table rows and column, but it shows in descending order, I want to show it in ascending order, for example the div which have multiple rows with data, it come first and the div that have less rows come second and so on in dynamically.
The whole process should be dynamically, for example if any div have many rows it come first and the less rows div come to next and so on, the whole process is based on data entry.
Below you can find an example of what I am thinking of, yet it's not working.
[image example for the better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHQAS.jpg)

```css
   
    .justrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
    .table {
    display: table;
width: 25%;
border:1px solid #ccc;
height: 100%;
}
  .table2 {
    display: table;
width: 25%;
border:1px solid #ccc;
height: 100%;
}
  .table3{
    display: table;
width: 25%;
border:1px solid #ccc;
height: 100%;
}
.header {
    display:table-header-group;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.rowGroup {
    display:table-row-group;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:25%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
text-align: center;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="justrow">
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="cell">Name</div>
    <div class="cell">Address</div>
    <div class="cell">Action</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Bob</div>
      <div class="cell">Address</div>
      <div class="cell">Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Joe</div>
      <div class="cell">Address</div>
      <div class="cell">Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
<div class="table3">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="cell">Name</div>
    <div class="cell">Address</div>
    <div class="cell">Action</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Bob1</div>
      <div class="cell">Address1</div>
      <div class="cell">Button1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">name1</div>
      <div class="cell">Address1</div>
      <div class="cell">Button1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">name1</div>
      <div class="cell">Address1</div>
      <div class="cell">Button1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">name1</div>
      <div class="cell">Address1</div>
      <div class="cell">Button1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">name1</div>
      <div class="cell">Address1</div>
      <div class="cell">Button1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">name1</div>
      <div class="cell">Address1</div>
      <div class="cell">Button1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">name1</div>
      <div class="cell">Address1</div>
      <div class="cell">Button1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">name1</div>
      <div class="cell">Address1</div>
      <div class="cell">Button1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
<div class="table2">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="cell">Name</div>
    <div class="cell">Address</div>
    <div class="cell">Action</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Bob</div>
      <div class="cell">Address</div>
      <div class="cell">Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Joe</div>
      <div class="cell">Address</div>
      <div class="cell">Button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Sue</div>
      <div class="cell">Address</div>
      <div class="cell">Button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Sue</div>
      <div class="cell">Address</div>
      <div class="cell">Button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Sue</div>
      <div class="cell">Address</div>
      <div class="cell">Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where does the data list come from? Is it possible to sort the data list before being displayed?

Comment: Please add the relevant code in a code block as text to the question itself, and define "_it's not working_".

Comment: the data come from the database, sometime one table have many rows and some time other this is not specify which table will be have many rows next, i want to have the many rows table in the first  the less next and so on. i mean if any of the above table have many rows it should come the first and so on. same as i have clarify it in the above picture attached.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that the data is retrieved from a database, so you know how many rows there are in a table and can define a `style="--row-count: ..."` with each table retrieved.

As each main `.table` is a *flexbox item*, you can use the table row count to modify the table *flexbox* `order` property and easily change its position inside a `.justrow`, without Javascript manipulation:

- `order`: `0` or `unset` -> place table in *document creation order*
- `order`: negative or lower value -> place table before tables with higher `order` values
- `order`: positive or higher value -> place table after tables with lower `order` values

MDN Reference: [Ordering flex items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

Given the above you can use *custom variables* for `.table` `--row-count` and `.justrow` `--order-sign` to set the required sort order for a row of tables.

Essentially, the *row count* determines the position of a table inside a row and the *sign* determines the sort direction.

The `--order-sign` can be defined for each `.justrow` individually, or just once in `:root` or `body` for all `.justrow` elements (*for ease of the demo, in the snippet I used `body` to define `--order-sign`*).

The equation is easy to understand: `order = order-sign x row-count`

```css
.justrow {
    --order-sign: -1
    /*
       -1 - Ascending order
        0 - no (or document) order
        1 - Descending order
    */
}
.table {
    order: calc(var(--order-sign) * var(--row-count));
}
```

```html
<div class="justrow">
    <div class="table" style="--row-count: X">table rows</div>
    <div class="table" style="--row-count: N">table rows</div>
</div>
```

In **the snippet** I added a second two-row table and a few radio buttons to toggle between sort orders:

```css
/* ADDED */
body   { --order-sign: 0 }
.table {
    order: calc(var(--order-sign) * var(--row-count));
}
/**/

.justrow {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

    /* added for demo */
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.table {
    flex: 1;        /* added for demo */
    width: 20%;     /* from 25% for demo */

    display: table;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 100%;
}
.header {
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.rowGroup {
    display: table-row-group;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

fieldset { margin: 0; margin-bottom: 1rem; }
[red]    { color: red; font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>&nbsp;Sort Order&nbsp;</legend>
    <label for="ord1" title="document order">
        <input id="ord1" class="radio" type="radio" name="group" checked
               oninput="document.body.style.setProperty('--order-sign', 0);">
        (None)
    </label>
    <label for="ord2" title="most rows first">
        <input id="ord2" class="radio" type="radio" name="group"
               oninput="document.body.style.setProperty('--order-sign', -1);">
        (Asc)
    </label>

    <label for="ord3" title="least rows first">
        <input id="ord3" class="radio" type="radio" name="group"
               oninput="document.body.style.setProperty('--order-sign', 1);">
        (Des)
    </label>
    <br><br>
    <span>MDN Reference: <a target="_blank" href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items">Ordering flex items</a></span>
</fieldset>


<div class="justrow">
    <div class="table" style="--row-count: 2">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Address</div>
            <div class="cell">Action</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell" red>table 1</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">Joe</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table" style="--row-count: 8">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Address</div>
            <div class="cell">Action</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell" red>table 2</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">name</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">name</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">name</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">name</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">name</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">name</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">name</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table" style="--row-count: 5">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Address</div>
            <div class="cell">Action</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell" red>table 3</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">Joe</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">Sue</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">Sue</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">Sue</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table" style="--row-count: 2">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="cell">Name</div>
            <div class="cell">Address</div>
            <div class="cell">Action</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell" red>table 4</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rowGroup">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">Joe</div>
                <div class="cell">Address</div>
                <div class="cell">Button</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Lende, its working fine and this is what i need it, can do it without Asc and Des buttons? it should automatically order when any table have many rows. once again thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @ibadullah Sure, the radios are there for demo only. Just set `--order-sign` in `body {..}` to what you need manually or adjust the `calc(..)`.